# (flex) - effect play on data change - custom itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, effect

I've got datagrid with custom itemrenderer. I want to play animatecolor effect for a cell in which data was changed. I don't want to play that effect for all cells.

Here is code of itemrenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Sequence id      =   "updateEffect">
        <s:AnimateColor colorFrom   ="0xffffff"
                        colorTo     ="0xb9d30d"
                        target  =   "{lblData}"
                        duration    ="5000"/>
        <s:AnimateColor colorFrom   ="0xb9d30d"
                        colorTo     ="0xffffff"
                        target  =   "{lblData}"
                        duration    ="5000"/>
    </s:Sequence>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
            if(data)
            {
                lblData.text = data[column.dataField];
                if(data.selected == true)
                {
                    lblData.setStyle("color","#61afda");
                    lblData.setStyle("textAlign","center");
                    lblData.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                    lblData.setStyle("fontSize","19");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingLeft","10");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingRight","10");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingBottom","0");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingTop","2");         
                    containter.setStyle("backgroundAlpha","1.0");
                    containter.setStyle("backgroundColor","0x2f3437");
                }
                else
                {   
                    lblData.setStyle("color","#d4d4d4");
                    lblData.setStyle("textAlign","center");
                    lblData.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                    lblData.setStyle("fontSize","12");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingLeft","10");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingRight","10");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingBottom","5");
                    lblData.setStyle("paddingTop","4");
                    containter.setStyle("backgroundAlpha","0.0");
                    updateEffect.play();
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:SkinnableContainer
    id          ="containter"
    width       ="100%"
    height      ="100%">

    <s:HGroup
        width       ="100%"
        height      ="100%">

        <s:Label
            id                  ="lblData"

            width               ="100%"
            height              ="100%"
            maxDisplayedLines   ="1"
            styleName           ="FPlayGcItemRenderStyle"/>


    </s:HGroup>

</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the best way but I generally add a listener to my data when I need to update properties dynamically in my item renderers.

```
//This is inside an item renderer
private var _myClass:FunkyClass;
override protected function set data( value:Object ):void
{
    super.data = value;
    if( value != null )
    {
        if( _myClass != null )
        {
            _myClass.removeEventListener( 
                  'MyFunkyClass.DataChange' , updateSomething);
        }
        _myClass = value as FunkyClass;
        _myClass.addEventListener( 
                  'MyFunkyClass.DataChange' , updateSomething);
    }
}

private function updateSomething( event:Event ):void
{
    //change colors, visibility and so forth
}
```

Of course your data class has to extend EventDispatcher.  I would also be interested in seeing how other folks in the community have solved this problem.